# Obtener numero de likes por post

Tags: sql, postgresql

estoy intentando obtener el numero de likes por post, pero, cuando me retorna las filas me trae registros repetidos. En la imagen se supone que el `post_id = 47` tiene 2 likes y aun asi me lo duplica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tablas ->
*Posts*:

```
    CREATE TABLE posts(
            id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            title VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE,
            description VARCHAR(255)
    );
```

*Likes*:

```
    create table likes (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        user_id INT NOT NULL,
        post_id INT NOT NULL,
        created_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
        updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp
    )
```

La consulta creada es la siguiente:

```
    select l.id as like_id, l.user_id, p.id as post_id, p.title, p.description,
    (select count(distinct likes.id) as total_likes from likes where p.id = likes.post_id)
    from posts p
    join likes l on l.post_id = p.id
    where l.post_id = p.id
```

Comment: ...`where l.post_id = p.id GROUP BY p.post_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hola para que no te lo duplique tenés que hacer un `GROUP BY` utilizando la función `count`.
[Aquí la documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp#:%7E:text=The%20SQL%20GROUP%20BY%20Statement,by%20one%20or%20more%20columns.)

Intenta con el siguiente *query* para mostrar el total de *likes* de cada *post*:

```
select p.id as post_id, p.title, p.description,
count(l.id) as total_likes
from posts p
inner join likes l on l.post_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.title, p.description;
```

Ten en cuenta que no podes agruparlo por `likes.id` porque te va a seguir saliendo duplicado. La otra alternativa es utilizar un *subquery*.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono.

Comment: El unico problema que no pense es que me trae solo los post con likes, no asi los post sin likes

Comment: Hola Ricardo, en ese caso si querés que salgan los post sin likes podés usar left join en lugar de inner join. Espero haberte ayudado y cualquier duda me comentas. Te dejo la documentación sobre los distintos tipos de SQL join: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Hola, gracias. Exacto habia hecho un left join en esa ocacion.